# Python - How to catch outside exceptions inside methods

Tags: python, exception

I want to know if there would be a way to catch exceptions inside called methods.

Example:

```
def foo(value):
    print value

foo(x)
```

This would throw a NameError exception, because x is not declared.
I'd like to catch this NameError exception inside foo method.
Is there a way?

Comment: This barely makes sense.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but there is a way to catch *every* exception that isn't handled:

```
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> def handler(type, value, traceback):
>>>     print "Blocked:", value
>>> sys.excepthook = handler
>>> 
>>> def foo(value):
>>>     print value
>>> 
>>> foo(x)
Blocked: name 'x' is not defined
```

Unfortunately, `sys.excepthook` is only called "[just before the program exits](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=excepthook#sys.excepthook)," so you can't return control to your program, much less insert the exception into `foo()`.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly that, but I'll try to figure out something with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The `NameError` occurs when `x` is attempted to be evaluated.  `foo` is never entered, so you can't catch the `NameError` inside `foo`.

I think what *you* think is that when you do `foo(x)`, `foo` is entered, and then `x` is looked up.  You'd like to say, "I don't know what `x` is", instead of letting a `NameError` get raised.

Unfortunately (for what you want to do), Python, like pretty much every other programming language, evaluates its arguments before they are passed to the function.  There's no way to stop the `NameError` of a value passed into `foo` from *inside* `foo`.

Comment: Sorry, I changed that. That's cause I wrote the method name 'method', but then changed the name.

Comment: @Gabriel: It doesn't make a difference.  `x` is still evaluated before the method is entered.  You could do `argument = x; foo(argument)` which would be nearly equivalent, but of course the `NameError` would just be raised sooner, although still outside of the method.